# LARAVEL8 - SAVE MODEL INSIDE OF FOREACH LOOP - FOR EVERY ITERATION

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8

Good Day, I have an array of cellphone numbers from the input, I want to loop through each of them and save them individually to the database.

SCENARIO: The user has 2 fields, Amount and cellphones. the cellphones come as an array I want to loop through and attribute the amount to each cellphone number. Eg. if I have an amount = 5, with 3 cellphone numbers, each cellphone will get 5.

````
        $product = $request->product;
        $float = Balance::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
        $rsn = mt_rand(100000000, 999999999);
        $sessionToken =(string) Str::uuid();
        $bundleId = $request->bundle;
    

        if(is_null($product)){
            return "Please select product";
        }else if($product ==1){//airtime
        
            $amount = $request->amount;
            $airtimePhoneNumbers = $request->airtimePhoneNumbers;
           
            if(str_contains($airtimePhoneNumbers, ';')){
                //multiple phone numbers, we split
                $phones = explode(';', $airtimePhoneNumbers);     
                        //load airtime for all numbers
                        if($float->float < ($amount * count($phones))-$amount){
                            return 'Not enough float to perfom this operation';
                        }else{

                        for ($i = 0; $i < count($phones); $i++) {
                            $rsn = mt_rand(100000000, 999999999);
                            $sessionToken =(string) Str::uuid();

                            Msisdn::create([
                                'requestType',
                                'product'=>$product,
                                'amount' => $request->amount,
                                'sessionToken'=>$sessionToken,
                                'bundleId'=>'airtime',
                                'rsn'=>$rsn,
                                'customerMsisdn'=>$phones[$i],
                                'trxnDescription'=>'descripti1on',
                            ]);

                                $float = Balance::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
                                $float->float = $float->float-$amount;
                                $float->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
                                $result = $this->asapCore->virtual_recharge($amount, $sessionToken, $rsn, $customerMsisdn, $transactionDescription, $requestType = 0);
                                $float->save();
                                return $result;
                        }
                    }
                    
            }else{```

ACTUAL RESULT: it only saves the first cellphone number and ignores the remaining ones.
RESULT EXPECTED: to save each and every cellphone number from the array.

I have tried to create a new Model inside the loop, it did not succeed.
````

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out what was the problem.

`$result = $this->asapCore->virtual_recharge($amount, $sessionToken, $rsn, $customerMsisdn, $transactionDescription, $requestType = 0);`

This line above was throwing an error message, that error was stopping the loop from the first iteration.